# Definitions of Creative Words

Tags: words, parashat-bereishit, creation

What is the difference between יצירה, בריאה, and עשייה? (Three terms for creation). The first is used in Genesis (1:1), the second in Genesis (2:7), the third in Genesis (1:11).

Comment: I'll see what I can find by way of sources, but I'm fairly certain that most understand ברא to have the connotation of creation ex nihilo; which is not true for the other words.

Comment: @Shokhet R. Soloveitchik writes this in several places in contradistinction to Yetzirah.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45020/3 Relevant: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1473/3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Ri ibn Shuaib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_ibn_Shuaib) explains in a [*d'rasha* on *B'reishis*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6059&st=&pgnum=4) that בריאה refers to creation [*ex nihilo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_nihilo), יצירה refers to creating a basic form, and עשייה refers to completing and arranging a thing in its final state:

> ומלת בריאה, פירשו בו ז"ל, הוצאת יש מאין. ויצירה, ציור הדבר. והעשיה גמר הדבר ותיקונו.

R' Aryeh Kaplan provides a similar explanation in his *Sefer Yetzirah: The Book of Creation in Theory and Practice* ([p. 43](https://books.google.com/books?id=aqc-61vr4q0C&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> In Hebrew, there are three words which have similar meaning. They are *Bara*, meaning "to create," *Yatzar*, meaning "to form," and *Asah*, meaning "to make." According to the Kabbalists, *Bara* indicates creation *ex nihilo*, "something from nothing." *Yatzar* denotes formation of something from a substance that already exists, "something from something." *Asah* has the connotation of the completion of an action.<sup>[101](https://books.google.com/books?id=aqc-61vr4q0C&pg=PA348#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The Vilna Gaon in [Aderes Eliyahu at the beginning of Parshas Bereishis](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14219&st=&pgnum=3) says *b'riah* is חידוש העצם, the creation of the "essence" of the object, *yetzira* is צורת הדבר בכמות, giving its dimensions or shape, and *assiya* is תיקון עשייתו, the set-up or preparation of its ongoing existence (the Gaon uses תקון to mean this in several contexts).