# Hebrew verbs in the Creation

Tags: hebrew, translation, creation, genesis-bereishith

Genesis 1 uses three distinct verbs when describing the Creation:

| Strong's # | Hebrew | Transliteration | English | Verses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H1254 | בָּרָא | bara' | to create | 1, 21, 27 |
| H1961 | הָיְתָ֥ה | hayah | to be | 2, 3, 14 |
| H6213 | וַיַּעַשׂ | `asah | to make | 7, 16, 25, 26 |

Most of these could be used interchangeably in an English translation.

Is there some significant difference in Hebrew between what in English means creating, causing to be, and making?

Comment: Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53965

Comment: @Fred, yes.  I'd delete this question, but as I was unable to find the other when I initially looked for an answer, leaving it here as a duplicate might help someone else find it in the future.  E.g. I said "verb" rather than "words" and used tags "genesis-bereishith" rather than "parashat-bereishit".

Comment: The question is slightly different. You ask about היה and not about יצר

Comment: Since the asker said he's happy to delete this as a duplicate of the other, I'm marking it as a duplicate. People will still be able to find that question using the keywords in this one.